# SQL SUM function for a column with integer name

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to return the sum of a column with an integer name (for example, a column named 251)

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfun(cid varchar(255))
RETURNS float
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT SUM(`cid`) FROM percentages);
END
```

I want it to return the sum of all the rows of the `cid` column of my percentages table, but it's instead returning the sum of the cids.

For example: if i call `myfun(251)`
if the values in the columns `251` are 1, 2, 3, and 4, I would expect an output of `1+2+3+4=10`
But it is returning `251+251+251+251=1004` instead

Comment: Simply `SELECT SUM(215) FROM percentages` ?  Make sure the 251 is within backticks..

Comment: Otherwise if that does not help see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You cannot parameterise the column name like that. The column names must be there so that the query can be compiled

Comment: @RaymondNijland it's giving me an error: ERROR: 
Unknown command '\`'.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's a dynamic table so i have to parametrise the column names

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want with standard SQL.  You simply cannot parameterize a column name, even with backticks, using regular SQL.

I can give you the hint that dynamic SQL (`prepare`/`exec`) can do what you want.

More importantly, I want to point out a flaw in your data model.  You presumably have many *columns* with the same information.  Instead, this data should be on separate rows.  Something like:

```
id    col    val
```

SQL is usually better with more rows rather multiplying columns.

Answer (score 0):

using dynamic sql and putting the column name in brackets, should work:

something like: 
declare @sql varchar(255) = 'SELECT SUM([' + @cid + ']) FROM percentages'
exec(@sql)